# Does appEmulation on Magento dispatch normal events for normal observers?

Tags: php, magento, dispatcher

For example, on `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` you have a method called `sendNewOrderEmail()` which runs this appEmulation, and generates the paymentBlocks to embed on the email.
I was told that this is done to simulate the frontend store and precisely be able to generate said block...

but does the methods called under that appEmulation also trigger observers on my custom modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. Area-specific events are enabled via the `app->loadArea([AREA])` call in the action controller superclass `preDispatch()`; see [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::preDispatch()` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L513). The areas are set by the child classes `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` and `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`.

If dispatching code is evaluated during script execution (e.g. a call to `Mage::dispatchEvent()`) then the event is dispatched. However, if observers are configured as area-specific (e.g. `frontend` and `adminhtml`) then those events will not dispatch unless that area is loaded.

For the final bit of reference, see `Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation::startEnvironmentEmulation()` and note that it does not call the load of an area.

Comment: But damn it does *sound* promising, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through the ringer trying to figure out exactly the same question you are asking.  I was trying to build an external SSO login. I noticed that none of the controller events were firing in the Mage_Customer module  etc.  The same methods should apply to you, just determine which controller you want to emulate and make sure to dispatch the same events in your code.

I've posted the results of all my research here...

[How can I trigger controllerless core Magento modules that watch <controller_action_predispatch> in <frontend> in config.xml from external script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201677/how-can-i-trigger-controllerless-core-magento-modules-that-watch-controller-act)

In retrospect, you *may* have solved my problem in a similar method with this 'core/app_emulation' thing. I am going to have to look more into it.

Comment: So... just to be clear... no events are dispatched when generating layout with 'core/app_emulation'?