# customer_logged_in Handle Isn't Added To Layout When Bootstrapped

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

```
// Include Magento application
require_once ( "../app/Mage.php" );
umask(0);

// Initialize Magento
Mage::app("default");

// Load the session
// This has to be done before getLayout() below or the blocks won't see the session
$session Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => 'frontend'));

// Get the primary layout
global $mageLayout;
$mageLayout = Mage::app()->getLayout();

// Set the layout XML to look for default and wordpress
$mageLayout->getUpdate()
    ->addHandle('default')
    ->addHandle('customer_logged_in')
    ->load();
```

(I realize that you shouldn't set the customer_logged_in handle all of the time. Via $session->isLoggedIn() I can do this dynamically. I have a larger problem.)

I have successfully be able to set additional handles using this code. (For instance, I have a handle called 'wordpress' that I use to change blocks being loaded into WordPress.) However, manually setting the customer_logged_in isn't working.

Why manually set it? Because the Customer Module's observer for controller_action_layout_load_before never fires. I've figured out how to get this observer to dispatch using [code suggested elsewhere on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201677/how-can-i-trigger-controllerless-core-magento-modules-that-watch-controller-act) however the observers code fails because $observer->getEvent()->getLayout() returns null.

So my problem is that, although I can access the session directly in my block's phtml files, and do logic with PHP, I can't take advantage of any logged-in/logged-out logic present in the Layout XML files because they rely on the customer_logged_in handle being set.

I don't know why the wordpress handle that I created can be set correctly, but the customer_logged_in handle is ignored. (As is customer_logged_out.)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

It is being added, but it's entirely possible that the content in the handle isn't being rendered.

Comment: The same block rendered inside Magento does include the content for this handle. (Specifically the links added by the Customer module to the top.links block.) Do you have any suggestions for finding out why it wouldn't render when loaded outside of Magento? (I am rendering the header block, and all other children including other links render correctly.) 

Thank you for your time.